# Adding a text area to a tabbed pane in java

Tags: java, swing, tabs, jtextarea, jtabbedpane

I have two files that I need to display in a program. I need to use JTabbedPane and each file should be displayed in its own tab. I can make the text appear in the tab, but the scroll bar won't appear, so I can't see all of the information in the file. How do I add the scroll bar to the text area?

I made one method that creates a panel with the text in it (this is for one file). Then, I made another method that has JTabbedPane and I added the panel to a tab.

Panel method:

```
private void makeTextPanel() throws IOException
{
    textPanel = new JPanel();        

    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setEditable(false);

    //width: 770 height: 1000
    textAreaDimensions = new Dimension(TEXT_AREA_WIDTH, TEXT_AREA_HEIGHT);
    textArea.setPreferredSize(textAreaDimensions);       

    BufferedReader inputFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILE_ONE));
    String lineOfText = inputFile.readLine();

    while(lineOfText != null)
    {
        textArea.append("\n" + lineOfText);
        lineOfText = inputFile.readLine();
    }

    // Add a scroll bar
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

    // Add the text area and scroll bar to the panel
    textPanel.add(textArea);
    textPanel.add(scrollPane);
}
```

Tabbed pane method:

```
private void makeTabbedPane() throws IOException
{
    frame = new JFrame("Project");   

    tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    frame.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    // add panel to the tab
    makeTextPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", textPanel);  

    // dimensions
    frameDimensions = new Dimension(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    frame.setPreferredSize(frameDimensions);


    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

To reiterate:

- How do I make the scroll bar visible?
- I set the height of the text area to 1000. Will the scroll bar be able to scroll through everything? If not, how do I set the height of the text area to fit everything in the file?

Answer (score 1):

The component you want scroll bars for should always a child of the JScrollPane. Adding the textArea and then the scrollPane to that tabbedPane probably isn't doing what you think it is.  Make sure that textArea is the child of scrollPane, and add just the scrollPane to the tabbedPane, ensuring you've specified a layout that dictates how the scrollPane is to take up the space you want within tabbedPane.

The scrollpane will automatically add scrollbars only when it decides the textArea is bigger than it can render in the space it's been given.

Question 1) The JScrollPane methods [setVerticalScrollBarPolicy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setVerticalScrollBarPolicy-int-) and [setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy-int-) will allow you to force the scrollbars to be always visible.

Question 2) The "preferred" height of the textArea is what your scrollPane will use to determine the scrollbar behaviour (see [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)).  It's all taken care of for you.  If not, you'd be forced yourself to consider font rendering height, how much text you put in the textArea etc.

Generally speaking, just throwing a JTextArea into a JScrollPane will see the desired behaviour you're seeking without you having to do anything "special" with JTextArea size.

Comment: I added this to my makeTextPanel() method                    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);                  The scroll bar stops at the height I set. How do I get it to scroll though the entire file? I set the width and height of the text area so that it would cover the gray space in the tab.

Comment: You are overriding the preferred size of the textArea component, which in turn is messing with what the JScrollPane will do with its scrollbars.  Trust the textArea to calculate its own perferred size based on the text that it's been handed instead of overriding the preferred size with your own static dimensions.

Comment: It worked! I removed the sizes for the text area. Now I ran into a new problem: I made another method that does the same thing but for another file, but then the text areas display the same information. I changed lineOfText and inputFile to lineOfText2 and inputFile2. I think the problem is that I'm calling two methods in the makeTabbedPane() method, so it will only display one of the files. Any ideas on how to display both files in different tabs? Thanks! (Sorry if I'm bothering you)

Comment: I'd much rather see what the code looks like. Can I suggest that you mark this question as answered, and post a new question with an SSCE of the code you're now struggling with?